# extract list of key:value from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I search a "**global**" solution to extract, from a dataframe's column, a list of *"key":"value"* to have each *"key"* as Column name and "*value*" as Value:

Before:

```
id, severity, user, events, city

1,Low,test1,[{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': 1653135398011, 'agent': None,...}], Athens
2,Medium,test2,[{'type': 'BBB', 'timestamp': 1653135398012, 'agent': STIX,...}], Buffalo
3,,test3,[{'type': 'CCC', 'timestamp': 1653135398013, 'agent': ACQ,...}], Carson
4,Low,test4,[{'type': 'DDD', 'timestamp': 1653135398014, 'agent': VTC,...}], Detroit
```

After:

```
id, severity, user, type, timestamp, agent,..., city

1,Low,test1,AAA,1653135398011,None, ..., Athens
2,Medium,test2,BBB,1653135398012,STIX, ..., Buffalo
3,,test3,CCC,1653135398013,ACQ,..., Carson
4,Low,test4,DDD,1653135398014,VTC,..., Detroit
```

On stackoverflow some solution extract 2 or 3 fields by their names, but if we don't know list content, how extract everything?
I think lambda function and/or regex will do the job but my skills are too bad...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
events_df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df["events"]:
    events_df = events_df.append(row[0], ignore_index=True)

pd.concat([df, events_df], axis=1).drop(["events"], axis=1)
```

I got it working with a `DataFrame` that looks like this,

```
   id severity   user                                             events  \
0   1      Low  test1  [{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': 1653135398011, '...   
1   2   Medium  test2  [{'type': 'BBB', 'timestamp': 1653135398012, '...   
2   3      NaN  test3  [{'type': 'CCC', 'timestamp': 1653135398013, '...   
3   4      Low  test4  [{'type': 'DDD', 'timestamp': 1653135398014, '...   

      city  
0   Athens  
1  Buffalo  
2   Carson  
3  Detroi
```

Edit:

Thank @Thyebri for the suggestion. It's possible to complete the same without using a loop. Though I am not qualified to say if it's more or less efficient.

```
events_df = pd.DataFrame(iter(df["events"].apply(lambda ls: ls[0])))
pd.concat([df, events_df], axis=1).drop(["events"], axis=1)
```

Comment: You code does indeed get the job done, but unfortunately creating an empty dataframe and appending rows one by one is a stupid idea as it is extremely inefficient and defeats the purpose of array programming, it is better to create the dataframe in one go. Nice effort, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what your question asks:

```py
from functools import reduce
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['events', 'city']), pd.DataFrame.from_records(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, df.events)), df['city']], axis=1)
```

Explanation:

- Using `functools.reduce()`, create a list of the dictionary objects in the `events` column
- Use pd.concat() to glue together (1) the columns preceding events, (2) a dataframe of columns in the dictionaries found in the values in the `events` column created using from_records(), and (3) the column(s) to the right of `events` (in this case, just `city`)

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','severity','user','events','city'], data=[
[1,'Low','test1',[{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': 1653135398011, 'agent': None}],'Athens'],
[2,'Medium','test2',[{'type': 'BBB', 'timestamp': 1653135398012, 'agent': 'STIX'}],'Buffalo'],
[3,None,'test3',[{'type': 'CCC', 'timestamp': 1653135398013, 'agent': 'ACQ'}], 'Carson'],
[4,'Low','test4',[{'type': 'DDD', 'timestamp': 1653135398014, 'agent': 'VTC'}], 'Detroit']])

print('Input dataframe:')
print(df)

from functools import reduce
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['events', 'city']), pd.DataFrame.from_records(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, df.events)), df['city']], axis=1)

print('\nResult:')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Input dataframe:
   id severity   user                                             events     city
0   1      Low  test1  [{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': 1653135398011, '...   Athens
1   2   Medium  test2  [{'type': 'BBB', 'timestamp': 1653135398012, '...  Buffalo
2   3     None  test3  [{'type': 'CCC', 'timestamp': 1653135398013, '...   Carson
3   4      Low  test4  [{'type': 'DDD', 'timestamp': 1653135398014, '...  Detroit

Result:
   id severity   user type      timestamp agent     city
0   1      Low  test1  AAA  1653135398011  None   Athens
1   2   Medium  test2  BBB  1653135398012  STIX  Buffalo
2   3     None  test3  CCC  1653135398013   ACQ   Carson
3   4      Low  test4  DDD  1653135398014   VTC  Detroit
```

NOTE: It was necessary to make slight changes to the dataframe shown in the question, such as putting quotes around the 'agent' values (STIX, ACQ, VTC).

Comment: @kobrakaye Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the answer is perfect and do the job. thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: Glad that it was helpful. Please consider marking one of the answers as "accepted".